# Synchronize Firefox bookmarks but use different "views"

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

My aim is to synchronize Firefox bookmarks on different devices but without merging them simplistically; instead, I would like the bookmarks from each device, although accessible by all devices, to be **stored separately from one another**.

To illustrate that, here is an example with a list of bookmarks from A to G shared between Device 1 and Device 2:

Device 1:

> - A
> - B
> - C
> - D
> - Bookmarks from Device 2: - E -F -G

Device 2:

> - E
> - F
> - G
> - Bookmarks from Device 1: - A - B - C - D

The bookmarks would be synced automatically, but when adding bookmark H from device 1 for example, it would appear on both devices but not at the same place in the hierarchy.

*(By contrast, a classical synchronization like performed by Firefox Sync would produce the same flat hierarchy for both devices, containing all bookmarks from A to G).*

This would be very handy for me to share my bookmarks (always stored on the Bookmarks Toolbar) between a personal computer and more work-related. All bookmarks would be available on both but each, for practical reasons, would have its own view with specific "top-level" bookmarks.

*I hope my description is clear.*

**I there a way for me to achieve that?** 
I have tried using Firefox Sync but it only merges the bookmarks. I also looked at a bunch of add-ons without any success.

Comment: I fixed what I believe to be an obvious typo; if I’m wrong (and it was what you wanted), please explain.  (I also tweaked the wording a little.)

Comment: You can import bookmarks & stick those under a dedicated node like you describe, but syncing doesn't work that way. Firefox has no way to know that what you stash under a node on one machine is the same as the main hierarchy on a different machine. So even if you managed to manually set this up, syncing couldn't maintain it. If there's a way to do it, it isn't native to Firefox. I haven't stumbled across an add-on that does this. You would need something like a bookmark manager that imports and compartmentalizes bookmarks from different computers and then does its own syncing to maintain them.

Comment: @fixer1234 I completely agree, as far as I have seen Firefox Sync does not work this way. It's a shame because if I'm not wrong previous versions worked this way when synchronizing bookmarks between Firefox Android and Firefox Desktop, the bookmarks from Android would appear in a dedicated folder of Firefox Desktop. 
I'm still going through add-ons but not sure I will find a suitable one.
Maybe some tweaking can be done with Profiles but it look likes when synchronizing the Profiles it will be back to square one.

Comment: Let me throw out a thought. How does Firefox maintain bookmarks? Is it in some sort of SQL database? How visible is that to users? How easy is it for users to hook into it? I can imagine a scheme where you have a database (external to Firefox) that contains *N* identical tables (one for each “device”), or maybe one table with a column that shows which “device” each row belongs to. Then use off-the-shelf software to sync the database across all machines, and some (simple?) home-grown scripts to export from Firefox to the master database, and to import into Firefox from the database.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Does this make sense? (ping @fixer1234)

Comment: @Scott, if you build the better mousetrap, the world may beat a path to your door.  The bookmark data structure is open source, and it's stored in the user profile.  Many other browsers can import it and maintain the original hierarchy, and there are various 3rd party bookmark-related add-ons.  There is probably some hidden complexity, like playing nice with Firefox's own use and syncing.  But you're right that it should be doable by someone with some programming skills.  I'm just not aware that this has already been done and available OTS.  Are you volunteering?  :-)

Comment: Maybe when I get a round tuit.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: @Scott It sounds indeed doable in theory. The bookmark data structure is fairly simple however, I am not confident at all in building myself the scripts for import/export from Firefox ;) If you give it a try one day, make sure to tell me :)

Comment: Note: until I find a good solution, I'm going back to not synchronizing the bookmarks and I will transfer bookmarks from a device to another using Firefox Pocket when needed. Not ideal, I will keep looking for a better way.

Comment: There exist a few services which claim the ability to share bookmarks. You could try them if you like: [TeamSync Bookmarks](https://teamsyncbookmarks.com/) , [Bookmark Ninja](https://www.bookmarkninja.com/), [Diigo](https://www.diigo.com/).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for the links. TeamSync bookmarks looks good and I actually gave it a shot in the past but was not convinced because it had a lot of defects (or at least, their Firefox extension). I see it has been updated since so I should maybe give it another try. Diigo and Bookmark Ninja don't have any free plans but I should check them out. But to be fair, the main downside of these kind of service is usually that it doesn't integrate with FF bookmarks and is essentially an improved link sharing service. But progress seems to have been made in integration with the browser.